# DAX / Power Query: Relabel rows if they all have same condition and also if they are sequential after the other

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I want to build a Power BI report, and looking for a solution using DAX based on the dataset already queried. If I need to add some power queries before building the DAX, I am ok too.

I have about 500,000 rows of data. Relevant columns are

1. Object ID
2. Contract ID
3. Start Date
4. End Date

Where all objects are unique, but the contracts are not unique. Different objects can belong to the same contract, and there are multiple contracts.

The contracts have start and end dates, but sometimes the contracts with same vendors might be directly continuing so the end date of one contract will be equal to the start date of the next contract. But the contract ID is different.

How do I relabel the contracts so that all the ones that are directly continuing from one to the next are grouped together?

[Edit 1]

Sample source data:

| Object ID | Contract ID | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | AB1 | 12/7/2023 | 22/7/2023 |
| 1002 | AB1 | 22/7/2023 | 30/7/2023 |
| 1003 | CD1 | 11/7/2023 | 25/7/2023 |
| 1004 | AB2 | 30/7/2023 | 11/8/2023 |

What I want is a fifth column, "Group ID" like below:

| Object ID | Contract ID | Start Date | End Date | Group ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | AB1 | 12/7/2023 | 22/7/2023 | AB1 |
| 1002 | AB1 | 22/7/2023 | 30/7/2023 | AB1 |
| 1003 | CD1 | 11/7/2023 | 25/7/2023 | CD1 |
| 1004 | AB2 | 30/7/2023 | 11/8/2023 | AB1 |

Where the Group ID inherits the first / earliest contract ID. The order of the rows can be random.

Totally at a loss, any advice welcome.

Comment: Please post sample source data (as text, not an image) along with sample of wht you want the output to be.

Comment: Do you guarantee that you never have 2 contracts ending on the same date or starting on the same date? Example could 1003 have started on 30/7/2023 and if yes, how would you know if 1002 continued to 1003 or 1004

Comment: @JoaoLeal if the contracts are with different vendors, the dates can be the same, but if it is with the same vendor (which we can tell by the contract ID “AB”, then the dates can never overlap more than the End Date = Start Date. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So anything with the same contract numbers is always continuous, or not?

Comment: @horseyride yes, if the Contract ID is the same, then the Objects are always continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how fast this will be with your data set, but first create a column called Vendor (the formula might need to be adjusted to your data since I'm just basing myself on the sample you've provided):

```
Vendor = LEFT('Table'[Contract ID], 2)
```

Then create another column called Group ID

```
Group ID = 
   VAR vendor = 'Table'[Vendor]
   VAR endDate = 'Table'[Start Date]

   RETURN LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Contract ID], 
          'Table'[Vendor], vendor, 
          'Table'[End Date], endDate, 
          'Table'[Contract ID])
```

You can probably do it in power query or in your source data as well and that would be faster. In SQL Server the functions to use are LAG and LEAD. I'm sure there's a way to do it in Power Query too.

Comment: thank you. i'm afraid directly in Power BI, i get stuck in the wheel of death of "Working on it". however you gave me a different idea to group the datasets before loading using similar logic as suggested. i will try it and update.